# what is the range of independent variable of a sinusoid?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, periodic-functions, angle

Let us say I represent a sinusoidal function as:
$$ y = \sin x $$

Then what will be its time period?

How to decide what is the range of its independent variable $x$ as we don't know if it is in time (*sec*) or angle (*degrees* or *radians*)?

Answer (score 0):

So to know the period you do the following.

Let $T$ be the period of $y = \sin(x).$ By definition, we have that

$$y(t) = y(t + T) \iff \sin{t} = \sin{(t+T)}.$$

Solving this equation, you have that

$$t = t + T + 2k\pi \vee t = -t - T +2k \pi, \text{ where } t \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

From this, you conclude that $T=2\pi$ (considering The least positive number.) In short, is the sine function, its period is $2\pi.$

For the second part, note that you can say that the domain in $\mathbb{R}$ even without knowing the *measure* you are using for the angles.

You should always specify if you are using time, degrees or radians. Because the values of your function will depend on that.

For examples, $y(\pi)$ will have different values if you consider $\pi \text{ rad},$ and $\pi \text{ degrees}.$ It’s up to you to decide what to use (unless it is stated that you shroud use a specific one), but always state it to avoid confusion.

Comment: so the period is 2π. Its in angle units. If I need to give the period in time units then how would I do that?

Comment: $2 \pi$ is in radians. To do for time units, all you have to do is to convert to time

Comment: I don't understand how do I convert radians into time?

Comment: For example, how much is $1$ minute in degrees or radians?